# Facebook's Graph Picture returns 429 over IPv6

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm using Python FaceBook-SDK to retrieve the avatars from the users on my site.

The request made to `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?width=300&height=300` returns a HTTP Status Code 429 (Too Many Requests) when the server is IPv6 capable, but the same request made with a server with only IPv4 stack works fine.

Debugging this on the IPv6 server using cURL with `-4` parameter the request works fine.

Question: Is there a setting in the Facebook API to enable IPv6?

**UPDATE:**

My "temporary" workaround was set the servers to use ipv4 over ipv6 editing the /etc/gai.conf and changing their precedence. But I dont know how I will handle it on servers without ipv4.